# htaccess não funciona

Tags: php, html, htaccess, servidor, url

já habilitei o htaccess no meu Apache e mesmo assim deu erro 500, alguém sabe me dizer se o problema é no código?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?page=$1
RewriteRule ^3-dicas-para-o-cabelo-crescer-mais-rápido/?$ /3 Dicas para o cabelo crescer mais 
rápido.php [NC,L]
```